# I'm having an error creating an registration using Firebase My app is actually running but when I pressed on register button It keep on showing fail

Tags: java, android, firebase-authentication

When I pressed Register Button It keep on showing error like failed to registered

**This is my Javacode**

```
import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.PatternMatcher;
import android.util.Patterns;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ProgressBar;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.google.android.gms.tasks.OnCompleteListener;
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.Task;
import com.google.firebase.auth.AuthResult;
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth;
import com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase;

public class RegisterUser extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener{
    private TextView banner, registerUser,alreadyhaveaacount;
    private EditText editTextFullname, editTextAge,editTextEmail,editTextPassword;
    private ProgressBar progressBar;
    private FirebaseAuth mAuth;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_register_user);
        mAuth= FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
        banner =(TextView) findViewById(R.id.banner);
        banner.setOnClickListener(this);
        alreadyhaveaacount=findViewById(R.id.alreadyhave);
        alreadyhaveaacount.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(RegisterUser.this, MainActivity.class);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });

        registerUser= (Button) findViewById(R.id.registerUser);
        registerUser.setOnClickListener(this);
        editTextFullname =(EditText)findViewById(R.id.fullname);
        editTextAge =(EditText)findViewById(R.id.age);
        editTextEmail =(EditText)findViewById(R.id.email);
        editTextPassword =(EditText)findViewById(R.id.password);
        progressBar = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.progressBar);
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        switch (v.getId()){
            case R.id.banner:
                startActivity(new Intent(this, MainActivity.class));
                break;
            case R.id.registerUser:
                registerUser();
                break;
        }
    }

    private void registerUser() {
        String email = editTextEmail.getText().toString().trim();
        String password = editTextPassword.getText().toString().trim();

        String age = editTextAge.getText().toString().trim();
        String fullname = editTextFullname.getText().toString().trim();

        if(fullname.isEmpty()){
            editTextFullname.setError("Fullname is Required!");
            editTextFullname.requestFocus();
            return;
        }
        if(fullname.length()>50){
            editTextFullname.setError("Input cannot be lower than 50!");
            editTextFullname.requestFocus();
            return;
        }
        if(password.isEmpty()){
            editTextPassword.setError("Password is Required!");
            editTextPassword.requestFocus();
            return;
        }
        if(password.length()<6){
            editTextPassword.setError("Password is too short!");
            editTextPassword.requestFocus();
            return;
        }
        if(age.isEmpty()){
            editTextAge.setError("Age is Required!");
            editTextAge.requestFocus();
            return;
        }
        if(age.length()>3){
            editTextAge.setError("Age cannot be higher than 3 digits!");
            editTextAge.requestFocus();
            return;
        }
        if(email.isEmpty()){
            editTextAge.setError("Email is required!");
            editTextAge.requestFocus();
            return;
        }if(!Patterns.EMAIL_ADDRESS.matcher(email).matches()){
            editTextEmail.setError("Please Provide a valid email!");
            editTextEmail.requestFocus();
            return;
        }

        progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        mAuth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
                .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                        if(task.isSuccessful()){
                            USer user = new USer(fullname,age,email,password);
                            FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Users")
                                    .child(FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid())
                                    .setValue(user).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
                                @Override
                                public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {
                                    if (task.isSuccessful()){
                                        Toast.makeText(RegisterUser.this, "User has been registered succesfully", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                                        progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                                    }else{
                                        Toast.makeText(RegisterUser.this, "Failed To Registered! Try Again", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                                        progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                                    }
                                }
                            });
                        }else{
                            Toast.makeText(RegisterUser.this, "Failed To Registered! Try Again", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                            progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                        }
                    }
                });

    }
}
```

**This is my Register_User.xml**

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#8BC34A"
    tools:context=".RegisterUser"
    android:orientation="vertical">


<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">


    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/banner"
        android:layout_width="271dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="176dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="176dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="177dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="177dp"
        android:fontFamily="sans-serif-black"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:text="Plantured"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:textSize="40dp"
        android:textColor="@color/black"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.497"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/registerUser"
        android:layout_width="380dp"
        android:layout_height="70dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="50dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="50dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="50dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="50dp"
        android:backgroundTint="#D322D60E"
        android:text="Register"
        android:textColor="#ffffff"
        android:textSize="26sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.492"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textInputLayout5"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.0" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/alreadyhave"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="Already have an account Login Here!"
        android:textColor="@color/black"
        android:textSize="23dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/registerUser" />



    <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
        android:id="@+id/textInputLayout"
        style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputLayout.OutlinedBox"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="50dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="50dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="1dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="50dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="50dp"
        android:hint="Fullname"
        app:hintTextColor="@color/black"
        android:paddingTop="5dp"
        app:counterEnabled="true"
        app:counterTextColor="@color/black"
        app:counterMaxLength="50"
        app:endIconMode="clear_text"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="1.0"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/banner"
        app:startIconDrawable="@drawable/ic_baseline_person_24">

        <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
            android:digits="abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ "
            android:id="@+id/fullname"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@drawable/rectangle"
            android:inputType="text"
            android:paddingStart="10dp"
            android:paddingLeft="10dp"
            android:paddingEnd="10dp"
            android:textColor="@color/black"
            android:textSize="20sp" />
    </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>

        <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
            android:id="@+id/textInputLayout2"
            style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputLayout.OutlinedBox"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="50dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="50dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="50dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="50dp"
            android:hint="Age"
            app:hintTextColor="@color/black"
            app:counterTextColor="@color/black"
            app:counterEnabled="true"
            app:counterMaxLength="3"
            app:endIconMode="clear_text"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textInputLayout"
            app:startIconDrawable="@drawable/ic_baseline_person_24">

            <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
                android:id="@+id/age"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@drawable/rectangle"
                android:inputType="number"
                android:paddingStart="10dp"
                android:paddingLeft="10dp"
                android:paddingEnd="10dp"
                android:textColor="@color/black"
                android:textSize="20sp" />

        </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>

    <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
        android:id="@+id/textInputLayout3"
        style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputLayout.OutlinedBox"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="50dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="50dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="50dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="50dp"
        android:hint="Password"
        app:counterEnabled="true"
        app:counterMaxLength="15"
        app:counterTextColor="@color/black"
        app:endIconMode="password_toggle"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:hintTextColor="@color/black"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textInputLayout2"
        app:startIconDrawable="@drawable/ic_baseline_lock_24">

        <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
            android:id="@+id/password"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@drawable/rectangle"
            android:inputType="textPassword"
            android:paddingStart="10dp"
            android:paddingLeft="10dp"
            android:paddingEnd="10dp"
            android:textColor="@color/black"
            android:textSize="20sp" />

    </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>

    <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
        android:id="@+id/textInputLayout5"
        style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputLayout.OutlinedBox"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="50dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="50dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="50dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="50dp"
        android:hint="Email"
        app:counterTextColor="@color/black"
        app:counterEnabled="true"
        app:counterMaxLength="40"
        app:hintTextColor="@color/black"
        app:endIconMode="clear_text"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textInputLayout3"
        app:startIconDrawable="@drawable/ic_baseline_email_24">

        <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
            android:id="@+id/email"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@drawable/rectangle"
            android:inputType="textEmailAddress"
            android:paddingStart="10dp"
            android:paddingLeft="10dp"
            android:paddingEnd="10dp"
            android:textColor="@color/black"
            android:textSize="20sp" />

    </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>

    <ProgressBar
        android:id="@+id/progressBar"
        style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleLarge"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:visibility="gone"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        tools:ignore="MissingConstraints" />
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

**this is the USer class **

```
public class USer {
    public String fullName, age, email,password;

    public USer(){

    }
    public USer(String fullName, String age,String email,String password){
        this.fullName = fullName;
        this.age=age;
        this.email=email;
        this.password=password;
    }
}
```

**This is the build.gradle(Project:App)**

```
   // Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.
buildscript {
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath "com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.2.1"
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.10'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
        // Warning: this repository is going to shut down soon
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

**This is the gradle.build(Module:app)**

```
    plugins {
    id 'com.android.application'
    id 'com.google.gms.google-services'
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion 30
    buildToolsVersion "30.0.3"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.authapp"
        minSdkVersion 19
        targetSdkVersion 30
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
}

dependencies {

    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.3.1'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.4.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.1.1'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:21.0.1'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:20.0.2'
    implementation platform('com.google.firebase:firebase-bom:29.0.0')
    implementation 'com.google.mlkit:image-labeling:17.0.5'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.+'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.3'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.4.0'


}
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

And this is the path from my firebase realtimedatabase `https://auth-9395f-default-rtdb.firebaseio.com/`

Comment: share your error code here

Answer (score 0):

The a `Task` fails, it contains an exception with the cause of the failure. Log/display that to find out the cause of the problem:

```
mAuth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
        .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
            @Override
            public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                if(task.isSuccessful()){
                    ...
                }else{
                    Log.e("Auth", "Failed to register", task.getException()); // 
                    Toast.makeText(RegisterUser.this, "Failed To Registered! Try Again", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                }
            }
        });
```

Comment: still doesnt work

Comment: "still doesn't work" is pretty much impossible to help with, so you're going to have to do better if you want us to be able to help you. What did you do with the code from my answer? What did the `Log.e` show in your logcat output for `task.getException()`?

Comment: actually im new to android stdio

Comment: the logcat show this

Comment: logcat: Unexpected EOF!
    
    This means that either the device shut down, logd crashed, or this instance of logcat was unable to read log
    messages as quickly as they were being produced.
    
    If you have enabled significant logging, look into using the -G option to increase log buffer sizes.

Comment: and also this E/libPowerHal: [perfLockCheckHdl_internal] cannot alloc handle!!! dump all user!!!

Comment: Neither of those is coming from `task.getException()`. When you log the exception as I showed in my answer, find "Failed to register" in the logcat and check what the exception is.